# Loading different data in array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

So I got this array setup called tableDateArray, which is defined in **SubClass.h**. Now im trying to change the data of the array on wether or not a button is selected.

My code in **MainView.m**:

```
- (IBAction)dateSpecifiedButtonTouch:(id)sender {

if (monthly.enabled == NO){
    NSLog(@"no");
    tableDateArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      @"January 2012",
                      @"February 2012",
                      @"March 2012",
                      @"April 2012",
                      @"May 2012",
                      @"June 2012",
                      @"July 2012",
                      @"August 2012",
                      @"September 2012",
                      @"Octobre 2012",
                      @"November 2012",
                      @"December 2012",
                      @"All months",
                      nil];
    }

if (monthly.enabled == YES){
    NSLog(@"yes");
    tableDateArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      @"2002",
                      @"2003",
                      @"2004",
                      @"2005",
                      @"2006",
                      @"2007",
                      @"2008",
                      @"2009",
                      @"2010",
                      @"2011",
                      @"2012",
                      @"All years",
                      nil];
}}
```

So the NSlog is tracing the correct value so that's not the issue. But my array will be filled with whatever state is selected first and is refusing to change the data. Im sure im overlooking something simple.

**Added per request:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; // unused method of type cell.
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [tableDateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

I dont think im calling `reloaddata` to be honest.

Comment: It is not mutable array if you want to change anything in array you must use Mutable Arrays

Comment: What is the problem with this array? Please expain in more detail

Comment: I bet you're displaying this in a table view, yes? Are you calling "`reloadData`" when you click the Monthly button?

Comment: @michael dautermann yes I am!

Comment: NSMutableArray (and all other classes with Mutable in the name) can be modified. So, if you create a plain NSArray, you cannot change its contents later (without recreating it). But if you create an NSMutableArray, you can change it — you'll notice it has methods like -addObject: and -insertObject:atIndex:.

Comment: @NishantTyagi I explained the problem. I want to change the data on wether or not a button is selected and currently its refusing to change data.

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen, Torylon ***is*** recreating the array each time that button is touched. The lack of a NSMutableArray is ***NOT*** the problem here.  And @Torylon needs to edit this question to show the "`cellForRowAtIndexPath`" method, and wherever he calls "`reloadData`", too.

Comment: I changed the array to a mutable array, still the same issue. Guess I have to change some of the code?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann : you said it right :)

Comment: You are using if and if statement..... rather if and else...

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Updating right now.

Comment: Question is updated with code as requested.

Comment: @Torylon: plz nslog `monthly.enabled` to check if its value really changes to `YES`

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I noted in my question that I did.

Comment: @Torylon: Above both the `if`

Comment: [Array removeallobject];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by using the `reloadData` as suggested. However, the `reloadData` had to be called in viewWillAppear otherwise it refused to update my tableView.

Code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the code provided till now it looks ok .No reason can be said from why not it is working

May be this is a little more right way to write the code

```
- (IBAction)dateSpecifiedButtonTouch:(id)sender {
    if (monthly.enabled)
    {
        NSLog(@"yes");
        tableDateArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"2002",
                          @"2003",
                          @"2004",
                          @"2005",
                          @"2006",
                          @"2007",
                          @"2008",
                          @"2009",
                          @"2010",
                          @"2011",
                          @"2012",
                          @"All years",
                          nil];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"no");
        tableDateArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"January 2012",
                          @"February 2012",
                          @"March 2012",
                          @"April 2012",
                          @"May 2012",
                          @"June 2012",
                          @"July 2012",
                          @"August 2012",
                          @"September 2012",
                          @"Octobre 2012",
                          @"November 2012",
                          @"December 2012",
                          @"All months",
                          nil];

    }
[table reloadData];
}
```

EDIT :

Ok for that purpose let me say there is 2 ViewControllers VC1, VC2

in VC1 you are updating the value and in VC2 the table with datasource array named inputArray.

- So in VC1 when button pressed
- Get the instance of vc2
- assign the array to VC2instance.inputArray=tableDataArray;
- Call refresh in table with reloadData

Comment: Plz tell the effect on else instead of checking for `NO`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I keep getting a "No known class method for selector 'reloadData'".

Comment: that table must be your tableview outlet instance

Comment: Im pretty sure it is..I am using different xibs and classes if that matters?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData

Comment: I added: @class DateSpecifiedViewController;
DateSpecifiedViewController *tableDate;. And then I changed the reload line to: [tableDate.tableView reloadData]; Which fixed the error from appearing but still doesnt change the array.

Comment: @LithuT.V Can you explain in more detail? I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Geez... so many answers have it all wrong.

Just call `[yourTableViewOutlet reloadData]` from the IBAction where the monthly button is being touched.

E.G.

```
- (IBAction)dateSpecifiedButtonTouch:(id)sender {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    [yourTableViewOutlet reloadData];
}
```

Of course you'll want to change "`yourTableViewOutlet`" to the true name of your table view that you've connected to an outlet.

Comment: well then +1 to your very fine answer, @LithuT.V

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Keep getting the same annoying error on the reloadData.. : no known class method for selector 'reloadData'. Code: [DateSpecifiedViewController reloadData];.

Comment: what's the name of your table view outlet *within* your "`DateSpecifiedViewController`" object?  also, is "`dateSpecifiedButtonTouch`" within the same view controller that hosts the table?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann dont really know what you mean by name of my table view outlet. To answer the second question: no it is not.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didnt connect my tableview to an outlet

Comment: I'll let @LithuT.V modify his answer to show how to update a table in a different view controller (either an exposed property or maybe a NSNotification).

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)dateSpecifiedButtonTouch:(id)sender {

    if (monthly.enabled == NO){
        NSLog(@"no");
        tableDateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]initWithObjects:
                          @"January 2012",
                          @"February 2012",
                          @"March 2012",
                          @"April 2012",
                          @"May 2012",
                          @"June 2012",
                          @"July 2012",
                          @"August 2012",
                          @"September 2012",
                          @"Octobre 2012",
                          @"November 2012",
                          @"December 2012",
                          @"All months",
                          nil];
    }

    if (monthly.enabled == YES){
        NSLog(@"yes");
        tableDateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]initWithObjects:
                          @"2002",
                          @"2003",
                          @"2004",
                          @"2005",
                          @"2006",
                          @"2007",
                          @"2008",
                          @"2009",
                          @"2010",
                          @"2011",
                          @"2012",
                          @"All years",
                          nil];
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)dateSpecifiedButtonTouch:(id)sender {
    //maybe toggle monthly.enabled here?
    [yourTableView reloadData];

}
static NSArray * tableDateArray = nil;
static NSArray * tableYearArray = nil;
+(void)initialize
{
     if(self == [MyCLass class])
     {
           tableDateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]initWithObjects:
                          @"January 2012",
                          @"February 2012",
                          @"March 2012",
                          @"April 2012",
                          @"May 2012",
                          @"June 2012",
                          @"July 2012",
                          @"August 2012",
                          @"September 2012",
                          @"Octobre 2012",
                          @"November 2012",
                          @"December 2012",
                          @"All months",
                          nil];

           tableYearArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]initWithObjects:
                          @"2002",
                          @"2003",
                          @"2004",
                          @"2005",
                          @"2006",
                          @"2007",
                          @"2008",
                          @"2009",
                          @"2010",
                          @"2011",
                          @"2012",
                          @"All years",
                          nil];
     }
}

//all of your tableview delegates/data sources:
{
     NSArray * dataSource;

     dataSource = monthly.enabled ? tableDateArray : tableYearArray;
     //use datasource as the datasource
}
```